# Bind Statistics (How to graph them into Cacti)

Tags: bind, cacti, graph

I have seen a couple of post on SF like;

- [Find out how many DNS Queries/month via WHM or SSH?](https://serverfault.com/questions/147311/find-out-how-many-dns-queries-month-via-whm-or-ssh)
- [Nameserver usage](https://serverfault.com/questions/455306/nameserver-usage)

I want to graph statistics on 2 bind resolvers and 2 bind authoritative servers (into [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)). It seems that adding the following to named.conf (or named.conf.options) enables the dumping of statistics when you run the file `rndc stats`:

```
statistics-file "/var/cache/bind/named.stats";
zone-statistics yes;
```

The stats in the named.stats file given are pretty poor;

```
cat /var/cache/bind/named.stats
+++ Statistics Dump +++ (1359639340)
success 25
referral 0
nxrrset 0
nxdomain 3
recursion 43
failure 0
duplicate 0
dropped 0
--- Statistics Dump --- (1359639340)
```

I believe there is a poor amount of statistics given because of the version of bind running, is that true?

```
named -version
BIND 9.4.2-P2.1
```

Look at all the stats [this chap](https://serverfault.com/a/149198/76598) gets for example. Do I need to upgrade bind to get better stats, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get much more statistics using Bind and then graph it in Cacti. For this I advice you to upgrade to Bind 9.6 and use scripted attached to post here (http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=42218) to get various statistics. Setup instructions are also listed there.

I found one more result from Cacti site: [Bind 9.7 Usertemplate](http://docs.cacti.net/usertemplate:host:bind9.7)

Comment: Note: That should probably say 9.6 or later, as 9.9 is the current stable release.

Comment: Yes it seems updating bind is the way to go, I was trying to avoid that but ho hum, I shall have to bite the bullet. Thanks :)